# Constructing a triangle

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to construct a triangle $\triangle  ABC$ with $\angle BAC = 24$ $AB=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $AC=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$?

I am really lost how to solve this.

Comment: Do you need to describe to someone how to do this? Or is a simple yes-or-no answer sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since all these numbers are in fact done by arithmetic of constructable numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$AB$ and $AC$ are constructible by consecutive arithmetic operations and taking of square roots, starting with a unit length. The problem lies with the angle (I assume that you mean $24$ degrees). This is $2\pi/15$ or $\pi/3-\pi/5$. It's easy to construct $\pi/3$. It happens that $\pi/5$ has a constructible cosine:$$\cos\dfrac\pi5=\dfrac{\sqrt5+1}{4},$$so the angle is indeed constructible as well.